# Grant access to one webpage and restrict all other using captive portal?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I will explain my problem as best as I can.

I have a router. People can connect to my router and when the connection is established, I want them to see a webpage where they can control another device. Webpage is local on a raspberry pi and is already functional, I just don't want the users to go to 192.168.1.245 since that's not really user-friendly.

As I said, the webpage is only reachable if you are connected to the Wi-Fi network. I read something about captive portals(with Wi-Fi dog), but they need a authentication server, is this true? (which I don't have and I don't have the expertise nor the time to set this server up) I use OpenWRT on the router.

My goal is to only grant access to one webpage and restrict all other access to the internet. But I have absolutely no clue in how to approach this. (I installed OpenWRT on the TP-Link AC1750) I still need to have an internet connection since I need to SSH into the raspberry pi.

I have very little to no experience with network engineering and I'm getting pretty desperate.

After some googline I tried these iptables in my firewall:

```
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT DROP # Drop everything we don't accept

iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.252 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.1.252 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.1.1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

The result that I expect:

Block every address except for the `192.168.1.1` and `.252`
Accept incoming SSH connections via ethernet

The result that I got:
Blocked every address except for the `192.168.1.252` (configuration panel is not reachable)
Blocked SSH connections via ethernet
Can't connect to router via Wi-Fi anymore. (My laptop can tho, since I was already connected or something?)

When I ping to `252` I get responses, when I ping `192.168.1.1` I'm getting a timed out response (so it's dropped?) and when I ping any other address on the network submask (`192.168.1.xxx`) I get a unreachable. (so it's rejected?)